# Highlight (and then remove) duplicate phrases in single cell

Tags: google-sheets, unique, transpose, google-sheets-formula

A CRM duplicated the company name in thousands of rows of data.
I would like to identify and remove the duplicate company names using Google Sheets (or another tool--I am agnostic about the solution, so long as it requires no or very little coding). The structure of the cells is like this:

```
ForwardJump Marketing ForwardJump Marketing
```

How can I identify duplicate cells and remove the duplicated content?

Thanks,
Josh

I tried using Google Sheets to remove duplicates function, but it appears to be designed for comparing one cell to another cell, whereas I want to compare data within a single cell.

I also tried using this method: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CrwFQqxzQn8, but it is for comparing one cell with another.

Comment: Slightly fragile, but if you're confident that the name has been repeated a consistent number of times (i.e twice as per your example), you can use a substring formula to get the first n characters of the name where n = (LEN("ForwardJump Marketing ForwardJump Marketing")-1)/2, given that there will be 1 separator if the value is repeated twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a header row and data is in column A, try this in another column and copy it down:

```
=join(" ",unique(transpose(split(A2," "))))
```

Or create another sheet and use this in any column:

```
=join(" ",unique(transpose(split(Sheet1!A2," "))))
```

Comment: Thanks @ed-nelson. The second join statement worked best for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can use transposed unique like this:

```
=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(Sheet53!A1:D1)))
```

[image: 0]

and then <kbd>**`CTRL`**</kbd> + <kbd>**`C`**</kbd> followed by <kbd>**`CTRL`**</kbd> + <kbd>**`SHIFT`**</kbd> + <kbd>**`V`**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks @player0. This did not work for me, but I think it was my fault because I couldn't provide a sample Google Sheet. I appreciate your help.